# Use jQueryForm XHR as HTML

Tags: jquery

I have this JS code (using jQuery Form plugin):

```
    function doLogin(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
        var userbox = $(xhr).html();
        console.log(userbox);
    }
```

I want to use `userbox` as a html, so I could cut out some part of it (using `find()`). What am I doing wrong here?

---

Full login code:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        'success': doLogin,
        'error': showError
    });

    function showError() {
        $('#loginForm').append('<div class="errorMessage" style="display:none">Błędny login lub hasło.</div>');
        $('.errorMessage').fadeToggle();
    }

    function doLogin(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
        var userbox = $(responseText).html();
        console.log(userbox);
    }

    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved, and it is - as almost always :) - my mistake.

As David Hedlund mentioned, `responseText` was the key. Here's updated code, is anyone needs it:

```
    function doLogin(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
        var userbox = $(responseText).find('div#userBar');

        $('#loginForm').after(userbox)
        console.log(userbox)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`xhr` is a reference to your XmlHttpRequest. Did you intend to write `$(responseText).html()`?

Comment: `$(responseText).html()` returns `null` while `$(xhr).html()` returns code (which isn't working with `find()` though).

Comment: How is `doLogin` called? what is returned from the server? what code does `$(xhr).html()` produce? what selector are you passing along to `.find`?

Comment: I've updated my question with full login code. I was wrong though, both `$(responseText).html()` and `$(xhr).html()` returns `null`, while `$(xhr)` alone returns whole page source code.